# Simple html/haml form submit button - Post doesn't work

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have a form from a model where I am trying to update multiple records with one submit. I couldn't get it working

Here is the haml code with slight ruby in it.

```
.container#questions
  .col-md-8
    - @questions.each do |q|
      - ans = @user.answers.where(question_id:q.id).first.try(:content)
        .edit-input
          %input.form-control.edit-answer{data: {question_id: q.id, url: api_v1_answers_path(), user_id: @user.id}, placeholder: "#{q.description}", value: "#{ans}"}
    %button#update-answers{:type =>'submit', :class=> 'btn btn-primary'} Update
```

Here is the html that gets generated

```
<div class="container" id="questions">
   <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="info">
         <div class="question"> Question1 </div>
         <div class="edit-input">
            <input class="form-control edit-answer" data-question-id="2" data-url="/api/v1/answers" data-user-id="46" placeholder="" value="example1">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
         <div class="question"> Question2 </div>
         <div class="edit-input">
            <input class="form-control edit-answer" data-question-id="3" data-url="/api/v1/answers" data-user-id="46" placeholder="" value="example2">
         </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="update-answers" type="submit">Update</button>   
   </div>
</div>
```

When I click on update button, I don't see any action or post happening

Comment: what language is this ?

Comment: I'm sure that's not HTML..

Comment: Its Haml which is eventually converted to html. Its what yaml is for xml.  To give some perspective, just paste some of your html code here and it will be converted to haml http://html2haml.heroku.com/

Comment: @codeObserver how about doing the opposite? i'm sure there are more HTML people than HAML..

Comment: Thanks. I updated the html snippet that gets generated